# How to open a photo in a new tab in Google Chrome with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, mac, keyboard, shortcuts, photos

I used to know this but can't remember it now and can't find the original website where I had learned it from.

In macOS, how can I use a keyboard command to get a photo to open in Google Chrome? I know how to copy, tab over to Chrome and paste it,  but those are too many steps.

There is actually just one step when you are on the photo (in the Photos app) to type a keyboard shortcut that automatically opens a Chrome tab and your picture is there - one step.

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serves me, I believe it to be: the mac equiv of the windows button (option?) + t. Or Ctrl + t.

Answer (score 0):

Using Photos 3.0, there does NOT  appear to be a built-in way to share to a browser (see pic) or export either.

[image: photos-app]

You can right-click on a photo and choose "Edit With -> Other" and choose Chrome, but I don't there's a way to assign a shortcut key to that.